# Idiom or phrase or proverb for When ever you need me you conveniently declare me the head of the department, other times i am no more than a nobody

Tags: phrases, expressions, idioms, proverbs

Idiom or phrase or proverb for When ever you need me you conveniently declare me the head of the department (of course an acting head usually to throw me under the bus to deal/make difficult decisions or give the bad news), other times i am no more than a no-body (or usually treat me like a slave).

Comment: This is no agony aunt forum but all the same, let's see: *disposable*, maybe? There could be better alternatives.

Comment: I would say @Ontamu has the right answer - However, keeping in line with what Kris has said, the word **expendable** could also apply

Comment: Appropriate Idiom : 'Why buy a dog and bark yourself ?'

Comment: @Nigel J: that does not completely answer the whole question the part which is nobody or slave, but that is a very good idiom, at least partly answering it and perfectly. The answer remains as a combination of "buying a dog while barking yourself and scapegoating as well"

Answer (score 2):

Hello I believe "Scapegoat" is what you are looking for.
Definition from Urban Dictionary:

> (n.) A scapegoat is an event person or object that is used to lay the blame on for all that goes wrong, regardless of the contributions of others.

Example: "You are just using me as a scapegoat when something goes wrong"

Another phrase that could work is "Take the heat"

> to take blame of or get punished for something, whether guilty or not.

Example: "You always want me to take the heat when things go bad"

Answer (score 0):

Not an idiom, but this [poem](http://web.stanford.edu/~bkunde/sul-news/poems/po_train.html) that seems to express what you are saying

> It's not my job to run the train,  The whistle I don't blow.  It's not
>   my job to say how far  the train's supposed to go.  I'm not allowed to
>   pull the brake,  or even ring the bell.  But let the damn thing leave
>   the track  and see who catches hell!